Remote Profiling in an IPv6 Environment
We are trying to evaluate JProfiler in a pure IPv6 environment, but connection attempts always fail.
The JVM startup looks like this:

java -agentpath:/opt/jprofiler14/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=nowait -jar /opt/app/api.jar

The agent attaches to the server and indicates that it is listening:

JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.

But any attempt to connect returns failure.  When I perform a netstat -aln the server indicates the JVM is listening on port 80, but no other ports are open.  So - the agent is in fact not listening on port 8849???
I suspect the agent is defaulting to binding on IPv4, so I also tried explicitly setting the address=... parameter.  I've tried it several different ways:

address=fd00::f599:f4ba:2:1
address=[fd00::f599:f4ba:2:1]
address="fd00::f599:f4ba:2:1"
address="[fd00::f599:f4ba:2:1]"

But every time, I get the following error response:
JProfiler> Using address [fd00::f599:f4ba:2:1].
JProfiler> ERROR: Could not convert address.

There must be some trick to getting JProfiler to bind to the v6 IP and allow an incoming session, but I'm stumped and cannot figure out how.  And as far as I can tell, the JProfiler documentation doesn't even mention the existence of IPv6...  Anybody ever gotten this to work?

Unfortunately, as of 14.x, the JProfiler agent requires IPV4. Pure IPV6 support is planned for JProfiler 15.

Thanks Ingo - regrettable, but good to know!
